# What is the meaning of the "Tal" in the Russian/Muldovan last name "Talsky"?

Tags: этимология, морфология, ономастика

As far as I can tell, "Tal" isn't a Russian word that has any specific meaning.  Is there some kind of translation or history of the sound Tal that would shed light on the meaning of this family name?

Comment: Most probably it is derived from Jewish name Tal and, thus, has nothing to do with Russian etimology.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief that *-sky* ending is common among Russian surnames, usually it is of Polish/Jewish origin.

Comment: Well my ancestors were Russian jews in the area of the Ukraine.  So it's more likely that it's the Hebrew Tal, meaning "dew" and not a Russian term of any kind?

Comment: There is a term таль: "Грузоподъемное устройство с ручным или моторным приводом.". In some dialects it is synonym for "оттепель". Dahl's dictionary lists таль as an old word for "залог, заложник" (captive): "Детей своих отдает в тали".

Comment: @danieltalsky it can also be connected to German Tal which means valley. A similar word could exist in Yiddish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the word таль is present in Russian, however I cannot tell if the origin of your family name is connected with any of the meanings:

- There is a term [**таль**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%29): "Грузоподъемное устройство с ручным или моторным приводом." According to Vasmer it is known used from 1720 (many sailor's terms were borrowed at those times).
- In some dialects the word **таль** is synonym for "оттепель" (it is connected with words "таять", "проталина").
- Dahl's dictionary lists **таль** as an old word for "залог, заложник" (captive): "Детей своих отдает в тали". 
  Vasmer's dictionary supports Dahl, the similar words exist in Ukrainian, Serbian-croatian and Slovenian languages:

  > **таль** м. "заложник", укр. таль, др.-русск. таль – то же (часто; см. Срезн. III, 922), сербохорв. та̏лац, род. п. та̏оца "заложник", словен. tálǝc, род. п. tálca. По мнению Р. Муха (WuS I, 47), родственно лат. tālea "саженец, молодая веточка", греч. τᾶλις, род. п. -ιδος "взрослая девушка", τῆλις, род. п. -εως ж. "стручковое растение", др.-инд. tālī "определенное дерево", tālas "винная пальма". О цслав. талии "ramus virens", которое он относит сюда же, см. выше, тал.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  This actually helps rule out that it's a Russian word since it seems unlikely the name would be referring to any of these things.  It seems more likely that it's the Hebrew "Tal" or "Dew".

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Фамилия Тальский указывает на имя основателя рода. Фамилия Тальский образована от еврейского мужского имени Таль (טל), которое в переводе на русский язык означает «роса».

Согласно другой гипотезе, фамилия Тальский имеет славянское происхождение и восходит к названию поселка в Хасынском районе Магаданской области, расположенного в долине реки Талой – Талая.

Первое упоминание о поселке Талая обнаружено в документах церковного архива поселка Ямска за 190-1906 годы. В них говорится, что купец Афанасий Бушуев в 1868 году открыл целебные свойства тальской воды, замораживал воду и продавал населению лед, как лечебное средство.

http://toldot.ru/urava/lnames/lnames_21068.html

Фамилия Тальский произошла от названия деревни Таль в Бобруйской области, деревни Талька в Игуменской области или городка Тальное в Уманьской области. (Эта информация взята из книги «A Dictionary of Jewish Surnames from the Russian Empire» Александра Бейдера, см. http://www.avotaynu.com/books/DJSRE2.htm). Очевидно, предок носителя этой фамилии был выходцем из одного из этих мест.